# Parsing XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have got this XML file which is not well formatted but I need to to parse this anyhow.I have tried all parsing options say DOM / SAX parsing but still could not achieve it, Tried [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

So could anyone please guide me how do I parse such not well formatted xml data.

Here's the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Employee>
<Name> Jack
<EMPID> EMP001 <Address> 12 CA, USA</Address> 
</EMPID>
</Name>
</Employee>
```

**Parsing Code**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(
                    "new.xml"));

            // normalize text representation
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element of the doc is "
                    + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("NAME");
            int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();


            for (int s = 0; s < listOfPersons.getLength(); s++) {

                Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
                if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element firstPersonElement = (Element) firstPersonNode;

                    // -------
                    NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement
                            .getElementsByTagName("Name");
                    Element firstNameElement = (Element) firstNameList.item(0);

                    NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out
                            .println("Name : "
                                    + ((Node) textFNList.item(0))
                                            .getNodeValue().trim());

                    // -------
                    NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement
                            .getElementsByTagName("EMPID");
                    Element lastNameElement = (Element) lastNameList.item(0);

                    NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out
                            .println("ID : "
                                    + ((Node) textLNList.item(0))
                                            .getNodeValue().trim());

                    // ----
                    NodeList ageList = firstPersonElement
                            .getElementsByTagName("Address");
                    Element ageElement = (Element) ageList.item(0);

                    NodeList textAgeList = ageElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("Address : "
                            + ((Node) textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue()
                                    .trim());



                }

            }

        } catch (SAXParseException err) {
            System.out.println("** Parsing error" + ", line "
                    + err.getLineNumber() + ", uri " + err.getSystemId());
            System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage());

        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Exception x = e.getException();
            ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You have not valid XML so I don't think you can use standard Java XML parsers to parse it

Comment: There is no way to parse unformatted XML file. Above XML doesn't have proper format. Correct it. Java API will take care of it. Don't write yet another Java API to read improper XML.

Comment: What do you mean with "all parsing options"? Could you explain a little more about your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sanitizing bad XML in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243919/sanitizing-bad-xml-in-java)

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try to parse it? I don't agree that this is illegal XML.

Comment: I wish that I could change this . But I need to parse this. Would String-SubString game gonna work ?

Comment: @mikea Parser is unable to read the Name and EMPID

Comment: But the problem is not with the format so it must be with your code. Can you post the code you are using to parse it.

Comment: If the error in XML has some regularity, consider interpose a patch-up step before feeding it to an XML parser ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the XML is, in itself broken XML parsing will fail.

Assuming that, despite broken, the XML file will always have that layout, you could use regular expressions to extract the data.

```
String str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n" +
                        "<Employee>\n" +
                        "<Name> Jack\n" +
                        "<EMPID> EMP001 <Address> 12 CA, USA</Address> \n" +
                        "</EMPID>\n" +
                        "</Name>\n" +
                        "</Employee>";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\n", "");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<Name>(.+?)<EMPID>(.+?)<Address>(.+?)</Address>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Name: " + m.group(1) + " EMPID: " + m.group(2) + " Address: " + m.group(3));
        }
```

Yields:

> Name:  Jack EMPID:  EMP001  Address:  12 CA, USA

What does this pattern do:

- `<Name>` will match the `Name` tag.
- `(.+?)` will match what text follows the `<Name>` tag but will stop matching the moment it finds `<EMPID>`, since it is not a greedy pattern due to the `?` added after the greedy operator `+` (this will be matched by the next section of the pattern. Also in this section, anything which matches will be placed in a group which can be later accessed.
- Once that the name is extracted, the engine will attempt to match `<EMPID>` tag.
- After that the `<EMPID>` tag has been matched, a process similar to step 2 will take place and the matched content will be placed in another group.
- As for the next step, the code will look for the `<Address>`
- Lastly, the regex will attempt to extract any characters which are in between the `<Address>` and `</Address>` tags and once again, anything that matches will be placed in a group.

Once that the regular expression parses the string, I am accessing the groups and printing their values. As an extra step, I am removing any new line characters to process the string as a one liner.

An introductory tutorial on regular expressions can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: how to get command over patterns? Can you plz suggest some link to study or any book ?

Comment: @AmitG: I have improved my answer, hopefully it will shed some more light on the matter.

Comment: @npinti This answer given me a lot of hope now. Thanks. Now I need to put that XML into such String format like "str"

Comment: @user1432151: The initial format of `str` is how my IDE (Netbeans) formatted it when I copy/pasted it from this site to the IDE. I am also removing any new line characters so essentially the string will be one long line.

Answer (score 1):

It is not well-formatted but it is well-formed http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document, you can parse it with any parser.

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse the XML after you have corrected it.
A well-formatted XML only have 1 value per XML-element, but may have multiple attributes:

```
<employee attribute="attrvalue">value-string or xml-element, not both</employee>
```

So a suggestion to how your XML should look would be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Employee>
    <Name> Jack </Name>
    <EMPID> EMP001 </EMPID>
    <Address> 12 CA, USA</Address> 
</Employee>
```

EDIT: However, if you are recieving the XML from a source that you cannot change, then there is basically only one option left for you - manually parsing the XML after converting it to a regular java String.

Try to utilize the different string-methods such as substring, indexof etc.
Example:

```
String empidStartElement = "<empid>";
String nameStartElement = "<name>";
String nameEndElement = empidStartElement;

String xml = "<employee><name>Jack<empid>emp001</empid></name></employee>";

Integer nameStartPosition = xml.indexOf(nameStartElement)+nameStartElement.length;
Integer nameEndPosition = xml.indexOf(nameEndElement);

String name = xml.substring(nameStartPosition, nameEndPosition);
```

Comment: I know this but as I have said above I'm getting this from server which I can not change. Please suggest me any other option I have in mycase which you are aware off

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line:

> NodeList listOfPersons = getElementsByTagName("NAME");

to:

> NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getChildNodes();

output:

> Root element of the doc is Employee
>
> Name : Jack
>
> ID : EMP001
>
> Address : 12 CA, USA